# get value from AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

This used to be my code:

```
//At "click" I retrieve value from myFunctionA and use it in myFunctionB
$("#myButton").click(function()
{
    var response = myFunctionA();

    if(response) myFunctionB(response);
});

//Inside myFunctionA I perform an AJAX call (you will see it's really and "SJAX")
function myFunctionA()
{
    var response = myAjax();

    return response;
}

//This is not really and AJAX because of the async:false
function myAjax()
{
    var myJSON = {}

    $.ajax({
        url: "some_url.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            myJSON = data;
        }
    });

    return myJSON;
}
```

The thing is that the above worked just fine. I request a value, wait for it, and then use it where I needed. Obviously that SJAX part shouldn't be done, I must do a real AJAX request. So while I was looking for a way to achive this I stumbled with questions like

[jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5316697/702353)

and really nice answers like

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/702353

and also started to read about [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and methods like `.done()`. However I'm not being able to achieve the same result of my original SJAX code. So my questions are:

- Is it possible to do what I want using an AJAX request?
- Can it be done without modifying the `.click()` code?

Here is the current code I'm working on

```
$("#myButton").click(function()
{
    var response = myFunctionA();

    if(response) myFunctionB(response);
});

function myFunctionA()
{
    $.when(myAjax()).done(function(response)
    {
        return response;
    });
}

function myAjax()
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: "someurl.php",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Nope, when using async methods it can't be done the way you want to do it, you have to wait for the call to finish, doesn't matter how many wrapper functions you add with return statements, if the result isn't there, you can't use it. As a sidenote, using synchronous calls is not the answer, the answer is to code around the asynchronous behaviour, and not expect syncronous results.

Comment: @adeneo What would the closest to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If it where me, I would just do -> http://jsfiddle.net/b67ed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what needs to be done:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() 
{
    $.when(myFunctionA()).done(function(response)
    {
        myFunctionB(response);
    });    
});

function myFunctionA()
{
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();

    $.when(myAjax()).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        dfd.resolve(data);
    });     

    return dfd.promise();    
}

function myAjax()
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: "someurl.php",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20803609/702353) on [part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20803318/702353) helped me a lot!