# get value from AJAX request [part 2]

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20789395/702353).

I think I may be close, but on the other hand, there's a chance I misundestood everything so far.

In the code below is my question as comment in code

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get some data via ajax, process it an return something in response.

I should mention that the code structure must remain as close as it can to what I'm posting here. That is:

- On click, a call to a function 1 is made
- That function 1 calls a generic ajax function 2
- Then 1 process the data returned from 2 and return something else
- Back to click event, with that response from 1 I can do whatever I want

HTML

```
<button id="myButtonA">test A</button>
<button id="myButtonB">test B</button>
```

JS

```
//data_A.txt = {"key":"some_value_A"}
//data_B.txt = {"key":"some_value_B"} 

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#myButtonA").click(function()
    {
        $.when(myFunctionA()).done(function(response)
        {
            showValue(response); //this echoes {"key":"some_value_A"}
            //Is it possible to echo "yes: A"? instead the whole object?
        });
    });

    $("#myButtonB").click(function()
    {
        $.when(myFunctionB()).done(function(response)
        {
            showValue(response); //this echoes {"key":"some_value_B"}
            //Is it possible to echo "yes: B"? instead the whole object?
        });
    });      
});

function myFunctionA()
{
    var execution = AJAX("data_A.txt");

    return $.when(execution).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        var response = "";

        if(data.key == "some_value_A")
        {
            response = "yes: A";
        }
        else
        {
            response = "no: A";
        }

        return response;
    });     
}

function myFunctionB()
{
    var execution = AJAX("data_B.txt");

    return $.when(execution).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        var response = "";

        if(data.key == "some_value_B")
        {
            response = "yes: B";
        }
        else
        {
            response = "no: B";
        }

        return response;
    });     
}

function AJAX(source)
{
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: source,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data)
    {
        return data;
    }).fail(function(error)
    {
        alert(error);
    });
}

function showValue(val)
{
    console.log(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use your own deferred object http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/ as in

```
function myFunctionA()
{
    var execution = AJAX("data_A.txt");

    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    $.when(execution).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        var response = "";

        if(data.key == "some_value_A")
        {
            response = "yes: A";
        }
        else
        {
            response = "no: A";
        }

        dfd.resolve(response);
    });     

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

The return from $.when is still the original deferred object used by $.ajax, as far as I know you can't/shouldn't http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/ change that.